# value paste a loop through file vba

Tags: vba, loops, paste

Good day, I have about 125 spreadsheets in a folder and want to consolidate all the data, that I put onto one sheet for each file, from all the spreadsheets onto a different workbook.  I have a loop through files in folder but it pastes the formula and not the actual values.  How could I do this with the below code?  I have searched through the site and anything that looks like it could work causes an error.  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
Sub LoopThroughFilesInFolder()
Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Set mainwb = ThisWorkbook
mainwb.Activate
Sheets("Engine").Select
Range("a2:c500").ClearComments

Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:\Desktop\Vessel folder 2016") 'Use path of the folder

For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files 'loop through the files

If fileobj.Name <> "Bronco.xlsm" And fileobj.Name <> "~$Bronco.xlsm" And      (FileSystemObj.GetExtensionName(fileobj.Path) = "xlsx" Or FileSystemObj.GetExtensionName(fileobj.Path) = "xlsm") Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

'copy the results from the just opened wb
wb.Worksheets("ZenGarden").Select
lastcell = Range("a2:EQ5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
Range("a2:" & lastcell).Select
Selection.Copy

'go to the mainworkbook and paste data
mainwb.Activate
Sheets("Engine").Select
If Range("a2").Value = "" Then
Range("a2").Select
Else
Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
ActiveSheet.Paste

wb.Activate
wb.Save
wb.Close
mainwb.Activate

End If



Next fileobj



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`, for example:

```
'Copy the range into Clipboard
wb.Sheets(1).Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Copy
'Setup target range to paste Clipboard values
Dim targetRange As Range
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)   
'Paste Values into target range
targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

So in your case it would look *something* like:

```
'copy the results from the just opened wb
wb.Worksheets("ZenGarden").Select
lastcell = Range("a2:EQ5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
Range("a2:" & lastcell).Select
Selection.Copy

'go to the mainworkbook and paste data
mainwb.Activate
Dim targetSheet as Sheet
Set targetSheet = Sheets("Engine")
Dim targetRange As Range
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)   
'Paste Values into target range
targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer Jeremy!  When I put your code into the VBA it comes back with an error in the line:     Set targetRange = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: Hi Andy, there is a holo checkbox next to each answer, ticking it gives you a couple of points and lets everyone know your question is answered.

Comment: Sorry for being a novice at this, but don't know where to plug your code into the orignal I sent?

Comment: I gave it a shot and it looks like the copy part worked but when it got to paste it kicked back a "User-defined type not defined" with this line: Dim targetSheet As Sheet.  Am I missing something?  Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Try WorkSheet, sorry I'm not in front of a PC